# Log in with an anonymous account

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently facing the problem, that the workload is to much. However, we still need a working admin panel. Instead of re-coding a complete administration panel I decided to only do statistics in there, and move the logic out of there.

I am using Laravel 5.5. We are getting the user id's from the specific person and simply log in with

```
<?php
  Auth::login($user);
?>
```

However, we do also track the latest activity of all users with a simple middleware as this:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!auth()->check()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    auth()->user()->last_action_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    auth()->user()->last_action_date = Carbon::now();
    auth()->user()->save();

    return $next($request);
}
```

This helps us keeping track of everything. Obviously I do not want to track any activity when I logged in with my administration rights, is there any idea how this could be possible? I have not found a way to provide custom data within the Auth facade.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every time ehen you use `auth()->user()` It will generate a new `\App\User` Instance. So first you want a create an instance with `auth()->user()`. then update the created instance.

As your codes.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!auth()->check()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    $user = auth()->user();
    // Checking the privilege
    // $user->privilege is the column that you store user privilege status
    if($user->privilege !=1){
      $user->last_action_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      $user->last_action_date = Carbon::now();
      $user->save();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Hey Ramesh. Thanks for your answer. This turns out to be a problem: If a user logs in, he would have privilege status 0. If I log in, the user would have privilege status 1. So in case the user uses the account at the same time, no actions would be logged.